# get $sum of items in the same document mongodb

Tags: mongodb

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5941240cdc8dd12a183337b0"),
    "item" : ObjectId("593e700d9f34350aac73231d"),
    "store" : ObjectId("593e7589a489ce07c899210d"),
    "itemcredits" : [ 
        {
            "expireDate" : "10/2019",
            "unitePrice" : "50",
            "itemCredit" : "5"
        }, 
        {
            "expireDate" : "12/2018",
            "unitePrice" : "50",
           "itemCredit" : "3"
        }
    ]
}
```

i want to query to get the total sum of itemcredits.itemCredit of the same document that match same store and item to get the result  = 8 for this example

Comment: They are "strings" and not numbers. You cannot do math on "strings". You need to fix your data in order to "sum" anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([{$group: {
    '_id': '$_id', 
    "total": {$sum: "$itemcredits.itemcredits" }
}}]);
```

itemcredits need to be integer